# Using the sigma function with different treatment of odd and even numbers

Tags: summation, notation

So, if one wants to add together $1^2$+$2^2$+$3^2$... for *n* amount of terms, the sigma function can be used, like this:

[image]

If one wants to double every even number in that sequence, like $1^2$+ $2$ $*$ $2^2$+ $3^2$+ $2$ $*$ $4^2$... for *n* amount of terms, two sigma functions can be used, like this:

[image]

**Now, my question is, what if I want to double every odd number instead?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on formatting math for this site.  If I wanted to double the even squares, I would write $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3+(-1)^k}2k^2$$  Now I imagine you can see how to double the odd squares.

Comment: Note:  I think you intended the argument of your second sum to be $(2k)^2$.

Comment: I also think the last $k^2$ should be $(2k)^2.$ Now if you had written your formulas in MathJax (see previous comment) this would take only seconds to fix.

Comment: @DavidK You're correct, and yes, I'll have to learn how to use MathJax. I'll fix the error.

Comment: @lulu Thank you!

Comment: @saulspatz I'm confused, isn't the "k" as an exponent to "(-1)" redundant since 1 to the power of anything is still 1?

Comment: $1^k=1$ for all $k$, but $(-1)^k$ is $-1$ whenever $k$ is odd.

Comment: @DavidK I got it now! Completely forgot about multiplication of odd numbers. This equation is genius

Comment: @saulspatz I get your equation now! You should make it an answer, I'll accept it. Not that the other answers are bad, but your answer was best suited for me, as I'm not too familiar with the floor and ceiling functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to double the even squares, I would write $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3+(-1)^k}2k^2$$Now I imagine you can see how to double the odd squares.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{ceil(n/2)} (2k-1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is

$$2\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{floor(n/2)} (2k)^2$$

Add that to yours and you can see why it works